# How to display two forms on the same page?

Tags: django

How to display two forms on the same page? I will be grateful for your help

This is my views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            user_profil = UserProfil(user=user, name=form.cleaned_data['name'], last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],city=form.cleaned_data['city'])
            user_profil.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        return render_to_response('access.html', {'formRegister':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render_to_response('access.html', {'formRegister':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if forml.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user_profil = authenticate(username= username, password=password)
            if user_profil is not None:
                login(request, user_profil)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        return render_to_response('access.html', {'formLogin':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        context = {'formLogin':form}
        return render_to_response('access.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my urls.py

```
url(r'^access/$','users.views.register_user'),
url(r'^access/$','users.views.login_user'),
```

access.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">{%csrf_token%}
{{ formRegister.as_p }}
<p><input type="submit" value="Rejestruj"/></p>
</form>

<hr>


<form action="" method="post">{%csrf_token%}
{{ formLogin.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

There is one template(access.html) and two views

When I replace urls.py(order):

```
url(r'^access/$','users.views.login_user'),
url(r'^access/$','users.views.register_user'),
```

Display only loginform

Comment: What error are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

What if you change the names of your form variable in the `return` statement i.e.

```
{'formRegister':form}
```

and the other one:

```
{'formLogin':form}
```

**UPDATE:**

In your url file, you could do the following:

```
url(r'^access/login/$','users.views.login_user'),
url(r'^access/register/$','users.views.register_user'),
```

The same template will still be used, but with different views to handle the forms.

Other alternatives include:

1. Putting different URLs in the action attribute of the two forms. Then you will have two different view functions to deal with the two different forms.
2. Reading the values of submit buttons from the POST data. You can tell which submit button was clicked, then handle the logic.